# Git issue Bitbake gets stuck at do_fetch?

Tags: git, yocto, bitbake, imx6

These are the contents of my git2 folder:

```
rama@RRCH21:~/repositories/oe-core/build/downloads/git2$ ls
anongit.freedesktop.org.pkg-config                 git.kernel.org.pub.scm.utils.dtc.dtc.git.done
anongit.freedesktop.org.pkg-config.done            git.kernel.org.pub.scm.utils.kernel.kmod.kmod.git
anonscm.debian.org.collab-maint.ncurses.git        git.kernel.org.pub.scm.utils.kernel.kmod.kmod.git.done
anonscm.debian.org.collab-maint.ncurses.git.done   git.linaro.org.toolchain.binutils-gdb.git
git.denx.de.u-boot.git                             git.linaro.org.toolchain.binutils-gdb.git.done
git.denx.de.u-boot.git.done                        git.linaro.org.toolchain.gcc.git
github.com.Cyan4973.lz4.git                        git.linaro.org.toolchain.gcc.git.done
github.com.Cyan4973.lz4.git.done                   git.sv.gnu.org.config.git
github.com.file.file.git                           git.sv.gnu.org.config.git.done
github.com.file.file.git.done                      git.toradex.com.linux-toradex.git.lock
github.com.mendersoftware.mender                   git.toradex.com.u-boot-toradex.git
github.com.mendersoftware.mender.done              git.toradex.com.u-boot-toradex.git.done
github.com.philb.update-rc.d.git                   git.yoctoproject.org.opkg-utils
github.com.philb.update-rc.d.git.done              git.yoctoproject.org.opkg-utils.done
github.com.systemd.systemd.git                     git.yoctoproject.org.prelink-cross.git
github.com.systemd.systemd.git.done                git.yoctoproject.org.prelink-cross.git.done
git.infradead.org.mtd-utils.git                    git.yoctoproject.org.yocto-kernel-tools.git
git.infradead.org.mtd-utils.git.done               git.yoctoproject.org.yocto-kernel-tools.git.done
git.kernel.org.pub.scm.fs.ext2.e2fsprogs.git       sourceware.org.git.glibc.git
git.kernel.org.pub.scm.fs.ext2.e2fsprogs.git.done  sourceware.org.git.glibc.git.done
git.kernel.org.pub.scm.utils.dtc.dtc.git
```

I dont see any linux name files(except the git.lock file) during the bitbake command you suggested, I waited 5 minutes and checked again the same.
 and it is again stuck here :

```
Initialising tasks: 100% |###########################################################################################| Time: 0:00:01
NOTE: Executing RunQueue Tasks
Currently  1 running tasks (64 of 65)  96% |####################################################################################   |
0: linux-toradex-4.1-2.0.x-2.7.5 do_fetch (pid 1125)  26% |###############
```

When I try to bitbake  core-image-minimal with the setup below:

```
NOTE: Resolving any missing task queue dependencies

Build Configuration:
BB_VERSION        = "1.32.0"
BUILD_SYS         = "x86_64-linux"
NATIVELSBSTRING   = "Ubuntu-14.04"
TARGET_SYS        = "arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi"
MACHINE           = "apalis-imx6"
DISTRO            = "angstrom"
DISTRO_VERSION    = "v2016.12"
TUNE_FEATURES     = "arm armv7a vfp thumb neon       callconvention-hard"
TARGET_FPU        = "hard"
meta-angstrom     = "HEAD:9625910bb4bb48b3f4d87a1e9ff3576d40bd656a"
meta-toradex-nxp  = "HEAD:c4f34b34bf34f44b974a7add623cafff17d880ad"
meta-freescale    = "HEAD:05681fdf8298bb441c15135eae424c7601b07e98"
meta-freescale-3rdparty = "HEAD:e55167c3c2770c07a475342f99cc2a3a23fbfa0c"
meta-toradex-tegra = "HEAD:8deaad62384fbe4f4079f62bb7fdfa70ef199236"
meta-jetson-tk1   = "HEAD:e8b87fe8da7c6fcffa37ab245f50082953cc1ee1"
meta-toradex-bsp-common = "HEAD:bb3fafea5a3094909c8d7fb3216c37210fcfc339"
meta-snappy       = "HEAD:f6df6a63756d9976bcccb5fefdbc64e5cc794c99"
meta-linaro-toolchain = "HEAD:5d2cb685217794293ea2bab18d7e62019c329d06"
meta-oe           
meta-efl          
meta-gpe          
meta-gnome        
meta-xfce         
meta-initramfs    
meta-systemd      
meta-networking   
meta-multimedia   
meta-python       = "HEAD:b40116cf457b88a2db14b86fda9627fb34d56ae6"
meta-lxde         = "HEAD:1bd36a4d0f7e1e9fdea9c4c991188bc1dc9da421"
meta-browser      = "HEAD:1569eeb9cc1b87632abbf35fbb05f4ac4eeb3987"
meta-qt4          = "HEAD:f389368dc86e745df14cab9eeb9a94bc02bd273e"
meta-qt5          = "HEAD:2c9f0e4eb0e9097f6f872ec1e1d81768a8ab5f1b"
meta-freescale-distro = "HEAD:cd5c7a2539f40004f74126e9fdf08254fd9a6390"
meta-toradex-demos = "HEAD:a08f1a3164e9ce16fca09f1f1c016b81eb1fcfaa"
meta              = "HEAD:93b7f83a4212409a55ddf568a34468d4f6ef2c06"
oe-meta-go        = "master:514b2a80a2a4235687e92fb28328bb3e7c2d6c74"

Initialising tasks: 100% |##########################################################################################################| Time: 0:00:04
NOTE: Executing SetScene Tasks
NOTE: Executing RunQueue Tasks
Currently  1 running tasks (716 of 2038)  35% |##################################                                                                 |
0: linux-toradex-4.1-2.0.x-2.7.5 do_fetch (pid 2686)  26% |###################
```

It always gets stuck at(as seen above) linux toradex with 26%, never goes beyong that. I tried cleaning, emptying tmp folder, gets stuck like this. Any solution that might work?

Thanks.

Comment: You can clone linux separately, place it in download folder and append a `.done` file. You can also tweak git config (search for packedGitLimit for instance).

Comment: Sure, i found the linux-toradex git and try to clone it, but I cant find the exact file name such as linux-toradex-4.1-2.0.x-2.7.5. I only found the linux-toradex.git link. I also tried to clone that and its stuck at 1%. Which branch am I supposed to checkout once its all downloaded?

Comment: This is the link I am referring to https://git.toradex.com/cgit/linux-toradex.git/refs/heads?h=colibri

Comment: what you can try is `bitbake -c fetchall virtual/kernel` and in same time go to <download folder>/git2/ and look what is the folder name.

Comment: updated question

Comment: there is a linux toradex file.git.lock? what does that mean?

Comment: so you can go to `~/repositories/oe-core/build/downloads/git2`, then `rm git.toradex.com.linux-toradex.git.lock`, `git clone git://git.toradex.com/linux-toradex.git git.toradex.com.linux-toradex.git` ; `touch git.toradex.com.linux-toradex.git.done` it should be ok

Comment: I will try this now, thank you!

Comment: but could you tell me why this could be happening?

Comment: it seems that it doesnt even start to clone, is there a problem with the toradex git site? it stops at 1% download...

Comment: linux git repos are big and need a lot of time to clone, especially on restricted host.

Comment: I see, but it seems stuck to me rather than slow?

Comment: still stuck at the same counting objects hasnt moved at all, I really think it is stuck.

Comment: It's not a yocto problem, it's a git one, you should add git tag to the question. Did you try to change git global [configuration](https://gist.github.com/nefethael/189b34cf31a4fc875d73f3c43db7aefa) ?

Comment: @Nayfe yes I have tried that as well

Comment: may be you have slow internet check once.

Comment: I dont have slow internet, I have checked that before posting this! I can download other big repos. its just the toradex stuff that doesnt load.

Answer (score 1):

Open your `linux-toradex-4.1-2.0.x-2.7.5.bb` file present in the path  `meta-toradex/recipes-kernel/linux`. Then take the git link present in `SRC_URI` variable.
Then go to other command link and give `git clone <git site >` check how much time it is taking to clone the `linux repo`. It will show the speed and data then you will come to understand the `bitbake` compile stuck or not.
e.g.: `git clone -b your-branch git://git.toradex.com/linux-toradex.git`

Comment: hi, I have tried that before, it does not clone, it gets stuck at counting the elements and doesnt go further. Im not sure if my git setting are wrong, but I can clone other repos?

Comment: this is it git clone git://git.toradex.com/linux-toradex.git git.toradex.com.linux-toradex.git

Comment: for me its cloning and working fine (downloaded 1.27 Gb data) so the problem is net speed you need to use super speed internet minimum 10MBPS.

Comment: The problem is not net speed :) I just downloaded a movie for 2 Gb, The problem is with git settings I am assuming, I tried tweaking them to no avail :(

Comment: It could be some kind of firewall as well, I asked the incharge he said they dint have any firewall so im baffled o.0

Comment: better re install the git and repo and try still not post again

Comment: not working still, no idea why I can pull from all other git repos, its strange...